# File parsing in Python

Tags: python, regex, parsing, logging

I've read some info about file parsing in Python but it is not quiet clear for me right now so I need some help.

I have a log file with strings that has specific markers as WARNING, DEBUG etc.
And i want to put all of them into different lists to work with them later.
So basically as I understand I need to use regexp to do so. The code that I have right now.

Part of code that will help you to understand where and what I want to put:

```
message = ('CRITICAL', 'ERROR', 'WARNING', 'INFO', 'DEBUG', 'AUDIT', 'TRACE')
crit, err, warn, info, deb, aud, tra = [], [], [], [], [], [], []
error = (crit, err, warn, info, deb, aud, tra)
```

Here is parser code:

```
with open(log, 'r+') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

    for line in lines:
        for i in range(len(message)):
            match = re.search(message[i], line)
            if match:
                new_line = match.group()
                error[i].append(new_line)
```

So the line in "for line in lines" itself grabs perfectly, but when I drop into "for i in range(len(message)):" and try to print match - it gives me an object and new_line appends only the word "WARNING" etc. So not the whole line, but I need it without any cut.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: if you need the whole line why don't you use `new_line = line` instead of `match.group()`?

Comment: yes I figured it out. I need to change the behavior to that one:
    for line in lines:
        for i in range(len(message)):
            if re.search(message[i], line):
                error[i].append(line)

Comment: If you simply want to check if `message[i]` can be found from `line` it can be done by `if message[i] in line:` without needing to use regex

Comment: I will try that also, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the line, append the line: `error[i].append(line)` and not the `match.group()`.